# maximum of Dawson function

Tags: calculus, gaussian-integral

I've run into the DawsonF (D(x)) function doing some integrals with Gaussians.  I would like to know the location of the maximum analytically, is this possible to obtain?  Numerically I get x=0.924139

Comment: [I don't think so](https://oeis.org/A133841).

Comment: Wow, didn't know this existed. Cool, thanks.